# Unusual image may contain hidden data

Tags: malware, steganography, appsec

I have received an image from a friend.
This is the image.
[image: Unknown image]

is there any way to detect any anomalies in this image.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Open it with a hex editor. Here we can see the PNG bytes at the beginning, as well as our standard IHDR and IEND chunks. There doesn't appear to be anything outside of this information that could pose as malicious. Otherwise there is no chunk data or standard that could potentially execute code on its own, outside of a possible vulnerability in older browsers.

The way that I did is by opening up a given file in a hex editor (I used Hex Workshop), and I would break it down by its [file format](http://www.libpng.org/pub/png/spec/1.2/PNG-Chunks.html). This should allow you to parse it into its individual chunks, and reveal any data within them.

If you are unfamiliar with such techniques, there are tools for PNG analysis to varying degrees.

Further investigation with standard antivirus. Symantec found no malware, neither did [this scan from jotti](http://virusscan.jotti.org/en/scanresult/c8cae90fc6f19d144374527c02e0835fa5a44a0a).

Comment: How can I use stego analysis techniques in this ?

Comment: I added some related information, let me know if you have any other questions.